# Open Layer map with multple line

Tags: openlayers

I am having difficulty in **creating multiple style on a single path in open layer maps**. i am able to draw a line but couldn't add other style on click of button. i have tried the new control but its creating new line instead of appending the previous one. but i want to change the path style like color by clicking on button above which will change the style and i can draw with the changed style and revert to normal styling if pressed again. please help me with it. stuck for hours on this?
thanks